# Prioritising task scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, priority

I have recently started using task scheduler to make an authentication window pop up when the workstation is unlocked. This doesn't need to be secure or anything, it's for monitoring time spent on the computer.

On my PC this works perfectly, the login window appears as soon as Windows unlocks. However, our family computer (Where this is going to be used) is much slower and the program can take anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minutes to open. The program I've written is an EXE, but a Python program that I scheduled the same way opens at the same time.

Is it possible to make Windows prioritise certain tasks over others to get my login prompt to open faster?

Just to be clear, the task **does** run but it takes a long time to do so.

Both computers run Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post does not exactly fit your case; it is for Window Server 2008, but I believe it will get you started in the right direction. The author states that it isn't possible to set priority from the Task Scheduler GUI, but by exporting the task as an XML file, you can edit it and adjust the priority. He gives the steps to do this and also links to a Microsoft help document on priorities.

https://bdbits.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/setting-a-scheduled-task-process-priority/